# How do I make Vim to memorize(remember) all the function and Class names?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm wondering how do I configure Vim so that it can remember all the function  and class names, like modern IDE's can predict some of that stuff for us.

Comment: You need something like [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags).

Answer (score 1):

First things first, Vim is not an IDE—let alone a *modern* one—so expecting it to do anything an IDE can do is ludicrous.

But did you read these help sections?

```
:help include-search
:help tags
:help ctags
:help cscope
```

By the way, IDEs (modern or not) don't "memorize" functions and classes. They usually index your project in real time and generally never "memorize" anything about your code for more than a few seconds.

Comment: "Index" word makes more sense I guess sorry for bad English . Is it possible that I can config .vimrc file instead of doing it manually ?

Comment: You could, but why would you? Vim is a text editor, not a task runner. Read those help sections, follow relevant links, try a few things and come back when you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ctrl + P
```

after typing some characters of search keyword name. Ctrl-P quickly finds anything that matches, and sorts by best-guess.

Comment: That's not the exact solution, I wanted to config my vim